suma valores con condiciones en SQL
Soy nuevo en SQL y me gustaría saber como puedo hacer una suma de la cantidad vendida por cada CodigoDeArticulo por NumeroDeTienda y por cada FechaFactura (teniendo en cuenta por fecha de factura día entero sin tener en cuenta horas).
Gracias a tod@s!!

Pues sería una simple consulta de agrupamiento por tres campos en la que eliminas la hora del campo DATETIME FechaFactura. Suponiendo que trabajas en MySQL sería:
SELECT CodigoDeArticulo,NumeroDeTienda,
  DATE(FechaFactura) Fecha,SUMA(Cantidad) CantidadVendida
  FROM tabla
  GROUP BY 1,2,3;

Recuerda añadir el código de tus intentos y evita la capturas de pantalla, siempre mejor en modo texto.

Es recomendable no usar números para referenciar columnas basandose en su posición. Lo ideal es agrupar por la expresión de cada columna.

Hola @LuisCazares, gracias por tu aportación, ¿y quién lo recomienda? Porque a mí me parece bastante más cómodo y evita el típico error de agrupar por campos que después no se ponen en el SELECT y muchos SGBD ya tratan de evitar forzando un error de sintaxis.

Se recomienda en los análisis de código que detectan anti-patrones, así como otros gestores de bases de datos que no lo permiten como SQL Server y Oracle  (solo en ORDER BY). Es más fácil escribir el código así, pero es más dificil analizarlo puesto que hay que regresar a identificar a que se requiere cada columna. Además, si se modifican las columnas, es posible que se tengan que cambiar múltiples números dependiendo de que se quite, agregue o cambie de lugar.

SELECT
CodigoDeArticulo,
NumeroDeTienda,
DATE(FechaFactura) AS Fecha,
SUMA(Cantidad) AS CantidadVendida
FROM 
GROUP BY
CodigoDeArticulo,
NumeroDeTienda,
Fecha
;

Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple). Ademas ese sql esta mal...
